Is the "You will excuse my being so much overpowered" used as sarcasm?
In Emma (2020), they are discussing about Frank Churchill:

Knightley: I should be as ready to acknowledge his merit's as any
other man, but... I hear of none, except that he is well grown and
good-looking.
Emma: Well, if he has nothing else to recommend him, he shall be a
treasure at Highbury.  We do not often look upon fine young men.
Cannot ask for all the virtues into the bargain.
Knightley: You will excuse my being so much overpowered.

The use of formal phrasing "excuse my being" combined with the
strong word "overpowered" creates a humorous contrast for me.
Is the "You will excuse my being so much overpowered" used as sarcasm?

Looking at the clip in a bit more context, it doesn't seem to have any special meaning except "Please excuse me for speaking my mind strongly".  They are discussing a man, Emma is in favour of him, Knightley is against, saying that his only good qualities are that he is good-looking.  Knightley feels that he may have expressed his opinion too strongly, and so insulted Emma, and he apologies - all in the measured, formal style of Jane Austin characters. Is it "sarcasm"?  You'll know better, if you know the personalities of the characters.  There is no special linguistic mark of "sarcasm". If you don't think the apology is genuine, then it is sarcastic.
I don't see any special sense, nor anything that is worth emulating as a learner.
